# Content owner only access in storage of firebase android Java

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am making a voice recording application in which the recording is saved in firebase storage in a folder named emailID (user email id when registered). I want that only the user can have access to that folder. Means that user can only open their own folder (matching name to their email). I want this feature to make my application more secure. I need the javascript code for the storage rules (according to my need) in firebase.

In this way, no one can get access to firebase storage until they log in, and after that, they can have access to their folder only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for this:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    // Files look like: "Zrecorder/<email>/path/to/file.txt"
    match /Zrecorder/{email}/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.token.email == email;
    }
  }
}
```

Also see:

- The Firebase documentation on [properties in the `request` variable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/storage#request)

Comment: Thank you so much, Frank. It's a brilliant way.  I am totally satisfied with this answer. Thanks for your time.